# Ontology vs. LLM for Query Expansion (or both?)

Tags: elasticsearch, search, nlp, huggingface-transformers, ontology

I work at a recruitment agency where as a job seeker you can search for jobs and as a recruiter you can search for candidates in our candidate pool that might fit the job description. Currently both search engines are based on Elastic Search with some handling of synonyms, but we still have problems with showing all relevant search results if the search term doesn't fit the job description or CV (for example if some specific frontend framework is required for a job, a candidate with experience in a similar framework should still be shown in the results but with slightly lower relevancy.

Without much consideration for different approaches (because we don't have much NLP Expertise in the company and have a quite new data science department), we already experimented with building an ontology based on external ontologies and our own data (e.g. Python is used in Data Science) to find closely related terms and expand the search queries based on those relationships. While this approach seems to work somewhat, it feels kind of cumbersome, outdated and will probably need a lot of maintenance in the long run. For example using a prompt in GPT yielded very similar results in a matter of seconds, which raises the question if, for example, just using the embeddings of the search terms would already be enough to expand a users search query with additional relevant terms.

What approach would you suggest when dealing with the problem of query expansion? Or would a combination of both approaches make sense (e.g. using an LLM to automate building an ontology). Are ontologies regarding that use case outdated or am i just falling for the ChatGPT hype?

I would very much appreciate your insights!

Comment: In my view both technologies can do the job (as you've already found out). The difference I can see here is that, with ontologies (or similar - sounds like something like semantic distance or cosine correlation could also work) you'd be keeping the expertise in house, i.e., the ontologies, in a human understandable format and with known expenses, while with an LLM you'd be relying on another company's model (and prices). Either solution is valid, it's a business choice.